# resolv.conf is changed when it passes for a while

Tags: domain-name-system, resolv.conf

I set up /etc/resolv.conf

```
domain example.local
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.108
```

but,a days later..!?

It's changed!!

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

192.168.1.1 is DHCPD

How to stop change it?

Answer (score 6):

Is the machine sourcing it's IP address from DHCP?

If so, `resolv.conf` will be turned over by the DHCP client, to reflect the details in the lease it receives.

Take a look at the manpage for the DHCP client you are using. For instance `dhcpcd` has a `-R` flag which prevents this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have a dhcp-client service setup on your machine, it is rewriting `/etc/resolv.conf` with values it receives from the dhcp server.

Answer (score 3):

to prevent dhcp client rewriting your settings you can put as well in dhclient.conf [ /etc/dhcp3 in debian, if you use isc's dhcp3-client ]

```
supersede domain-name "your.domain.name";
supersede domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.108 ;
```

this might look differently for other dhcp clients.

Answer (score 1):

on my debian squeeze

open file:
/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

remove comment from line:

```
# prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

to

```
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

note the trailing semicolon